# Issue in rendering swagger-editor in react second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I am embedding swagger-editor package into my react application, when i fetch the swagger specifications from github, first time it works fine and validate it perfectly, but when i render it second time, it throws error like below, after this error it skips some validation and its really defeat the purpose as this primary purpose is to validate the spec errors. i understand swagger-editor spawns the webworker, and second time also its starts new instance and the previous instance remains there. Is there anyway to overcome this situation?

error is this 'Worker caught an error: Error: schema with key or id "openapi-2.0" already exists'

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue, and looking on swagger-editor github repo, I found this [issue 2339](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/2339).

It seen you have to terminate the webworker process.

[Worker Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/terminate)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.